# Sharepoint Office365 REST API not working in browser

Tags: javascript, office365, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I'm trying to read data from our Office365 Sharepoint site (on
*ourserver.sharepoint.com*) and use it in a customer site I'm developing that is currently running on my localhost.

I've extracted the X-RequestDigest header from a successful connection to Sharepoint (using Postman to mimic the calls I want to make).

The REST API call I tried to include in my Javascript code running in the HTML app looks like this:

```
$mightymouse.api.xhr("/_api/Lists/getbytitle('Event')/items", {
  type: "GET",
  dataType: "json",
  headers: {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": "0x7D5..."
  },
   xhrFields: {
     "withCredentials": false
  },
  crossDomain: true}).then( function okCallback(response)...
```

The response I'm seeing in my Chrome Developer tools for the request is a HTTP status code 403 and the following response:

`{"error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource."}}}`

I tried to mimic the calls using Python, and the thing that is different is the cookies I could send with Python that I can't send with Javascript, notably `FedAuth`and `rtFa`.